# Find marginal distribution of X and Y and the expectation of XY

Tags: probability, statistics

This is an exercise that confuse me
$$ let \ \ x,y \in \{0,1,2......\}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)=\frac{e^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!},x=\{0,1,...\}, y=\{x,x+1,...\}$$
$$ otherwise \ \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y) = 0$$

1. In the solution, when computing the marginal distribution of Y, the solution use
   $$\mathbb{P}(Y=y)= \sum_{x=0}^{y} \frac{e^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!}$$
2. Then when computing the expectation of XY, the solution use:
   $$\mathbb{E}(XY)= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} xy \frac{e^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!}$$

I am confused about the range of x as why it takes different range in 1 and 2? and x={0,1,...} does not suggest the limit of the range of x is y right?

Comment: In the bottom expression should be $\sum_\limits{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_\limits{y=0}^{\infty} xyP(X=x,Y=y)$ with $P(y<x) = 0$   So, $\sum_\limits{x=0}^{\infty} \sum_\limits{y=x}^\infty$ or $\sum_\limits{y=0}^{\infty} \sum_\limits{x=0}^y\cdots$ would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support is $$x = \{0, 1, \ldots \}, \quad y \in \{x, x+1, \ldots \}.$$  If we write this out in an (inverted) table, it looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
5 & * & * & * & * & * & * \\
4 & * & * & * & * & * \\
3 & * & * & * & * & \\
2 & * & * & * & & \\
1 & * & * & & & \\
0 & * & & & & & \\
\hline
(x,y) & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\end{array}$$
So when computing the marginal probability $\Pr[Y = y]$, we are picking a fixed row of the table, and summing over the $x$-values for which there is a $*$ in the table; i.e.,
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=0}^y \Pr[X = x, Y = y],$$ which is consistent with what you wrote in item 1.

When computing the expectation $\operatorname{E}[XY]$, the sum needs to be taken over every $(x,y)$ pair in the table that contains a $*$.  This can either be written as
$$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \sum_{y=\color{red}{x}}^\infty xy \Pr[X = x, Y = y]$$
or
$$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \sum_{y=0}^\infty \sum_{x = 0}^{\color{red}{y}} xy \Pr[X = x, Y = y].$$
In either case, we cannot sum over all nonnegative $(x,y)$ pairs, since the summand
$$xy \Pr[X = x, Y = y] = xy \frac{e^{-2}}{x! \, (y-x)!}$$ is not well-defined for integers $y < x$.  The factorial $(y-x)!$ in the denominator is undefined for negative integers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super clear explanation!!!